# How to fix NameNotFoundException in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I got PackageNotFoundException com.google.android.webview, after 25/March/2019 in my app, The users mostly affected used android version 5, 6 or 7, the user mostly uses Samsung or LGE devices. The exception I saw in an analytics tool and has affected many users since then.

I read a few threads saying crash occurs in lollipop devices after web view gets updated, but in my case, I am getting the exception in devices with android version 6or 7 as well, I already tried reproducing the error but no luck with that.

**Stack trace for the Error:**

```
Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
com.google.android.webview
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:235)
android.webkit.WebViewFactory.fetchPackageInfo (WebViewFactory.java:107)
android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass (WebViewFactory.java:183)
android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider (WebViewFactory.java:158)
android.webkit.WebView.getFactory (WebView.java:2290)
android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated (WebView.java:2285)
android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode (WebView.java:2344)
android.view.View. (View.java:4065)
android.view.View. (View.java:4186)
android.view.ViewGroup. (ViewGroup.java:591)
android.widget.AbsoluteLayout. (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
android.webkit.WebView. (WebView.java:609)
android.webkit.WebView. (WebView.java:554)
android.webkit.WebView. (WebView.java:537)
android.webkit.WebView. (WebView.java:524)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:631)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:706)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:774)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:716)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:847)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:380)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6904)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1136)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3266)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3415)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:229)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1821)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7325)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: I am also having a similar problem with my app. Did you find a way to resolve this problem?